# accumulative recursion drracket, totalling transactions

Tags: racket

Use accumulative recursion to write a function called update-balance that consumes a list of transactions, lot, a starting balance at the beginning of the month (considered day 0), start-bal, and a non-­‐negative number representing a minimum balance, min-bal. The function produces the balance of a bank account after completing all of the transactions in lot.

Having a problem with use of accumulative recursion

```
(define (trans-val t start-bal min-bal)
       (cond
         [(symbol=? (trans-action t) 'withdraw)
          (cond
            [(>= (- start-bal (trans-amt t)) min-bal)
             (- start-bal (trans-amt t))]
            [else (- start-bal (+ 1 (trans-amt t)))])]
         [else
          (cond
            [(>= (+ start-bal (trans-amt t)) min-bal)
             (+ start-bal (trans-amt t))]
            [else (+ start-bal (- (trans-amt t) 1))])]))
```

Comment: You procedure is not recursive at all. It just acts on a single "transaction" struct `t`. Also can you clarify what should happen if you try to withdraw and get an balance smaller than `min-bal`. In this code you just add 1 to it and withdraw anyways, I'm not sure that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```scm
(define (update-balance lot start-bal min-bal)
  (if (null? lot)
      ; no more transactions to process -> return start-bal
      start-bal
      ; take next transaction (t), calculate new balance
      (let* ((t (car lot))
             (new-bal ((if (eq? (trans-action t) 'withdraw) - +) 
                       start-bal 
                       (trans-amt t))))
        ; if new balance >= minimum balance, use that, otherwise retain previous balance
        ; in any case, tail-recursively call update-balance to process the next transaction
        (update-balance (cdr lot) 
                        (if (>= new-bal min-bal) new-bal start-bal) 
                        min-bal))))
```

Testing:

```scm
> (update-balance (list (trans 'deposit 100) (trans 'withdraw 80)) 0 0)
20
> (update-balance (list (trans 'deposit  10) (trans 'withdraw 80)) 0 0)
10
```